# How can I convert a string which contains an Array of Objects back to an Array?

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving a stringified Array of Objects in JS:

```
"[{version:07/18,test:true}]"
```

How can I get this back to an Array I can work with in JS? I've tried `JSON.parse` but this don't worked:

```js
var abc = "[{version:07/18,test:true}]";

console.log(JSON.parse(abc));
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: `JSON.parse` didn't work because that isn't valid JSON. I'd say the issue worth solving is whatever is sending you data in such an awful format :)

Comment: Where does that string come from? Maybe the source can be modified to provide valid JSON, I.E. `'[{"version":"07/18","test":true}]'`.

Comment: @TylerRoper Sometimes you don't have your hands in other companies stuff :) I need to work with this somehow.

Comment: I'd say you need more of an attempt, personally, as there's a fair bit of complexity here. For example, even if you `eval` this (*boo hiss*), it's still not right; e.g. `{ version: 07/18 }` will produce a giant decimal.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use JSON libraries with something is not valid JSON format.  It looks like you are going to have to roll your own solution here

Comment: @Mr.Jo I would handle this by contacting that company "Hey, just FYI, you guys have a bug somewhere and are producing invalid JSON."

Comment: If another company provides this API maybe you can ask them for support on how to convert their data format to a JS data structure since it's not JSON.

Comment: @James Yes, I'll try to do this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the *stringified Array of Objects* you have isn't a valid `JSON` string, the `JSON.*` functions can't deal with it.

A solution is to create your own parser that deals with the type of strings you have and returns an `array` of `object`s created from those in the string.

I created a one for you :

```js
/**
* a function designed to parse strings like the one you have
* it can deal with multiple objects in that string.
* @param arrLikeStr a string that as the one you have. Begins with "[" and ends with "]" and as much objects enclosed in "{" and "}" and separated with ",".
**/
const populateArrray = arrLikeStr => {
  /** remove "[", "]" and spaces **/
  arrLikeStr = arrLikeStr.replace(/[\[\]\s]/g, '');
  /** split the string based on '},' to get the objects in that string and loop through them **/
  return arrLikeStr.split('},').map(item => {
    /** represents the current object (item) that is parsed **/
    const obj = {};
    /** remove "{" and "}" from the current item **/
    /** split it based on "," and loop through **/
    item.replace(/[{}]/g, '').split(',').forEach(key => {
     /** split based on ":" to get the objects's attributes **/
      key = key.split(':');
      /** construct the object **/
      /** "true" and "false" are represented as boolean true and false **/
      obj[key[0]] = ['true', 'false'].indexOf(key[1]) !== -1 ? Boolean(key[1]) : key[1];
    });
    /** return the object after constructing it **/
    return obj;
  });
};

/** tests **/

const str = "[{version:07/18,test:true},{version:17/03,test:false}]",
  arr = populateArrray(str);

/** print the whole parsed array **/
console.log(arr);

/** print the second object in the parsed array **/
console.log('second object:');
console.log(arr[1]);

/** print the version of the first object in the parsed array **/
console.log('first object version:');
console.log(arr[0].version);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't fix the source you aren't left with any great options. You could use a library such as [relaxed-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/relaxed-json) to parse JSON with missing quotes on keys, but it doesn't handle the `07/18` so you will need to quote that first.

```js
const str = "[{version:07/18,test:true}]";

// Quote strings in the format 07/18:
const quoted = str.replace( /\d+\/\d+/g, '"$&"' );

// Parse with relaxed-json
const result = RJSON.parse( quoted );

console.log( result[0].version );
console.log( result );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/relaxed-json@1.0.3/relaxed-json.min.js"></script>
```

This is fragile code, that might work now for what you need, but will stop working if the source ever includes any other weird values that don't match the `\d+/\d+` pattern. I recommend that if you use something along these lines, you treat it as a temporary solution, and keep putting pressure on the maintainer of the data source to return their data as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

hope this approach works with you

replace each , by },{ then convert the string into array using split method (",")

```
// original string : "[{version:07/18,test:true}]"

var arr;
abc = abc.replace("," , "},{"); // "[{version:07/18},{test:true}]"
arr = abc.split(","); // [{version:07/18},{test:true}]
```

then you can parse each element in the array alone

```
JSON.parse(arr[0]); // {version:07/18}
JSON.parse(arr[1]); // {test:true}
```